# How to decrease the size of character varying type in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to decrease  the size of a character varying field in a postgres database table.

description | character varying(500)  | not null

i am using this command

```
ALTER TABLE notification ALTER COLUMN description TYPE varchar(200);
```

it's give me this type of error

**ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(200)**

So how to decrease size of character varying from 500 to 200?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you have values in that column that are longer than 200 characters. You first need to truncate those values:

You truncate the value as part of the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

```
ALTER TABLE notification 
   ALTER COLUMN description TYPE varchar(200) USING left(description, 200);
```

Alternatively you can first update the table, but doing it as part of the `ALTER TABLE` will be faster:

```
update notification 
  set description = left(description, 200)
where length(description) > 200;
```

After that you can run your `ALTER TABLE` statement